# Can someone explain to me what the i in the following code means (css)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble finding out what the i means in the css below. Can someone please explain to me it's purpose and why use it? Thanks.

```
.social li a:hover i {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There exists an `i` tag in html

According to http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/i.html

> The HTML i element makes its content rendered in italic font style. The presentational nature of this element makes it a good candidate for deprecation in future versions of HTML, so the general recomendation is to stop using it.

It is actually just the tag to make things italic. *like this*

This piece of css affects all italic text in the link where you hover over.

Comment: Funnily enough, instead of being deprecated due to its current purpose, HTML5 changes its meaning instead to something more semantically useful. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element

Answer (score 3):

Consider :

```
<ul class="social">
    <li>
        <a href="#">This is a <i>sample</i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This  : `.social li a:hover i {  }`  will focus on `sample` in the above eg.

**DEMO** : http://jsbin.com/UcotesUj/1/ Hint : Try hovering your mouse over the text sample and see the magic..:)

Explanation:

The above selector means

Select any element having `class` of `.social` and than further select nested `li` element  and than further select the `a` tag which is nested inside `li` and then on `hover` apply the properties to `i` tag which is nested inside that `a` element.

So the selector targets the `i` element which is used for making the text `italic` in your HTML

```
<i>Hey, this is italic</i>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy for all your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, any token that begins with a letter means that tag. So `i` matches the `<i>` tag, which is used for italic elements.